# Get Mounted Drives in c#

Tags: c#

`DriveInfo.GetDrives()` will enumerate all volumes mounted with a drive letter, but is there any way (without p/invoking Win32) to enumerate raw volumes, or to see volumes that may be mounted in a folder and not a drive letter?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, using WMI (Windows Management Interface)

The [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class contains information on physical hard drives, which can then be further examined to get a list of partitions.

There's also a decent tutorial on [using WMI from C# and .Net](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-WMI-with-C-4e5a9ee1)